# Add options to upvalues

Tags: latex, optional-arguments, upvalues

I have some objects that I want to present in TeXForm.

Thus, it is easily to do as follows:

```
YoungTableau/:TeXForm[YoungTableau[diagram_]]
```

However, what if I want to extend the functionality of TeXForm, 
but only when working with this particular object? Say that I wish to be able to specify if I want line breaks or not in the output.

I can do it like this,

```
YoungTableau/:TeXForm[YoungTableau[diagram_],OptionsPattern[]]
```

but then `OptionValue[LineBreaks]` will not work,
since I have not added this as a possible option. It IS possible to do it as follows:

```
Unprotect[TeXForm];
Options[TeXForm] = {LineBreaks->True};
Protect[TeXForm];
```

but this feels too intrusive. Should I just give up, and invent my own version of TeXForm which can take options?

What alternatives are there that does something similar to what I want?

Comment: `OptionValue` and `OptionsPattern[]` are magical constructs, which work by certain macro-like trick at run-time. So, I am not surprised that `OptionValue` did not work here. I would suggest to use it's long form: `OptionValue[f, {opts}, optionName]`, and declare options as `opts:OptionsPattern[]`, rather than just `OptionsPattern[]` - it will work then, and you can attach options to any symbol you want.

Comment: Ah, I suspected that it saw so sort of hack. Yes, this works. The only nuisance is that TeXForm[YoungTableau[...], LineBreak->True] looks like it is invalid, since ", LineBreak->True" appears in red in the front-end. But I guess I have to live with this, unless I want a new name instead of the TeXForm function.

Comment: You could include options into `YoungTableau` instead, to avoid red coloring, although this is probably conceptually wrong, since it is probably not the business of `YoungTableau` object to manage options for presentation. So yes, the only other simple and reasonable alternative seems to be defining your own `texform` function.

Comment: I thought so...

Comment: You could also `Unprotect` the `TextForm` function, and define your own, more liberal pattern for the `SyntaxInformation` for it. This is much more gentle interference with `TexForm`, and it will remove the red coloring. I'd actually probably go this way.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin. Please write up your comments as an answer. I think what you wrote is extremely valuable and needs to be put on record as an answer.

Comment: @m_goldberg All right, done.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`OptionValue` and `OptionsPattern[]` are magical constructs, which work by certain macro-like trick at run-time. So, I am not surprised that `OptionValue` did not work here. I would suggest to use it's long form:

```
OptionValue[f, {opts}, optionName],
```

and declare options as

```
opts:OptionsPattern[],
```

rather than just `OptionsPattern[]` - it will work then, and you can attach options to any symbol you want.

Regarding the red coloring problem for `TexForm`, there are a few choices. You could include options into `YoungTableau` instead, to avoid red coloring:

```
YoungTableau /: TeXForm[YoungTableau[diagram_ ,OptionsPattern[]]]
```

although this is probably conceptually wrong, since it is probably not the business of `YoungTableau` object to manage options for presentation.

You could also `Unprotect` the `TexForm` function, and define your own, more liberal pattern for the `SyntaxInformation` for it. This is much more gentle interference with `TexForm`, and it will remove the red coloring. I'd actually probably go this way.

Finally, you could define your own `texform` function, which would give you the most flexibility, and complete independence of built-ins.